# Meaning of output shapes of ResNet9 model layers

Tags: python, pytorch, resnet, modelsummary

I have a ResNet9 model, implemented in Pytorch which I am using for multi-class image classification. My total number of classes is 6. Using the following code, from torchsummary library, I am able to show the summary of the model, seen in the attached image:

`INPUT_SHAPE = (3, 256, 256) #input shape of my image`

`print(summary(model.cuda(), (INPUT_SHAPE)))`

[image]

However, I am quite confused about the -1 values in all layers of the ResNet9 model. Also, for Conv2d-1 layer, I am confused about the 64 value in the output shape [-1, 64, 256, 256] as I believe the `n_channels` value of the input image is 3. Can anyone please help me with the explanation of the output shape values? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes
your `INPUT_SHAPE` is `torch.Size([3, 256, 256])` if it's channel first format AND `(256, 256, 3)` if it's channel last format.
As Pytorch model accepts it in channel first format , for you it shows torch.Size([3, 256, 256])

and talking about  our `output shape [-1, 64, 256, 256]`, this is the output shape of your first `conv` output which has 64 filter each of `256x256` dim and not your `input_shape`.
`-1` represents your variable `batch_size` which can be fixed in `dataloader`